# Help with discrete mathematics "mod".

Tags: discrete-mathematics, modular-arithmetic

I'm kinda stuck on this exercise for discrete mathematics with mod. I know what to do if the numbers don't have exponents. What should i do in this situation:

$
3^{302} + 7^{200} \mod5$

If someone can please explain the steps too. 
Thank you.

Comment: You gotta give us some context.  Do you know Fermat's Little Theorem?

Comment: Welcome to stackexchange. There are general methods for this, but here the numbers are small enough so that you can start the work by hand. Begin by finding the powers of $3$ mod $5$, one at a time. Look for a pattern. Then $7$. Do you see why $2$ would be easier?

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). If you wait for someone to help you format, you'll never learn it by yourself. Additionally, if you don't know where to start, it might be better to ask for a hint rather than a full answer.

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

Express $3^{302}$ as $9^{151}$, and $7^{200}$ as $49^{100}$. Now can you find $9$ and $49$ modulo $5$?

Comment: Well 9(mod 5) = 5 * 1 + 4 and 49(mod 5) = 5 * 9 + 4

Comment: @Leaf Yes, you have found the general form $5k+4$. However, is $4$ the only solution? Look for a negative number.

Comment: I can 5 * 2 - 1 and 5 * 10 - 1 i will get the same result.

Comment: When you subtract $5$ each time to a number, it will still be the same modulo $5$. So $19, 14, 9, 4$ are all $4$ modulo $5$. What is the next number in the sequence?

Comment: I guess its -1.

Comment: @Leaf You got it!. Since $9$ and $49$ are both $-1$ modulo $5$, now you can calculate $-1^{151} + -1^{100}$. What do you get?

Comment: I get 0 is that correct?

Comment: @leaf Yes, well done!

Answer (score 1):

If you write out the powers of $3 \mod5$, you'll start to see a pattern:

\begin{matrix}
3 & 9 & 27 & 81 & 243 & 729 & \dots \\
3 & 4 & 2 & 1 & 3 & 4 & \dots
\end{matrix}

The second line gives the powers $\mod5$.

In particular, $3^4 \equiv 1 (\mod5)$. Thus $3^{302} = 3^{300} \cdot 3^2 = (3^4)^{75} \cdot 3^2 \equiv 1^{75} \cdot 3^2 \equiv 4 (\mod5)$

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following,
\begin{align}3^{302}+7^{200}&\equiv 2^{302}+2^{200}\mod5\\
&\equiv 2^{200}(2^{102}+1)\mod5\\
&\equiv  2^{200}(4^{51}+1)\mod5\\
&\equiv  2^{200}(4+1)(4^{50}-4^{49}+\cdots+1)\mod5\\
&\equiv  0\mod5
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

Use Fermat's Little Theorem

> If $p$ is a prime number, then for any integer $a$ we have 
>   $$\begin{align}a^{p-1}&\equiv1\mod p\end{align}$$

$$\begin{align}3^{4}&\equiv1\mod5\\(3^4)^{75}&\equiv1\mod5\\3^{300}&\equiv 1\mod5\\3^{302}&\equiv3^2\mod5\equiv4\mod5\end{align}$$

$$\begin{align}7^4&\equiv1\mod5\\(7^4)^{50}&\equiv1\mod5\\7^{200}&\equiv1\mod5\end{align}$$

Hence
$$\begin{align}3^{302}+7^{200}&\equiv1\mod5+4\mod5\\&\equiv(1+4)\mod5\\&\equiv5\mod5\\&\equiv\boxed 0\mod5\end{align}$$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

$$3^0\bmod 5=1,\\3^1\bmod 5=3,\\3^2\bmod5=4,\\3^3\bmod5=2,\\3^4\bmod5=1$$

and the sequence is periodic wiht period 4. You can infer that $3^{302}\bmod5=4$.

Apply the same reasoning with $7$.